# KeyError: "The name 'loss:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'loss', does not exist in the graph."

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensor

> KeyError: "The name 'loss:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'loss', does not exist in the graph."

**Hey guys, i'm facing an issue while using the tensorflow model. The code is running fine when it compiled in terminal but when i try to make it an python API it shows the above error**

```
output_layer = 'loss:0'
input_node = 'Placeholder:0'

# Crop the center for the specified network_input_Size
augmented_image = crop_center(augmented_image, network_input_size, network_input_size)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    prob_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_layer)
    predictions = sess.run(prob_tensor, {input_node: [augmented_image] })
```

The above code is saying an error at

`prob_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_layer)`

Comment: Did you happen to resolve this please?  Getting the same issue running this sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-model-python

Comment: Bgr_image is an undefined parameter. Replace it with augmented_image as that is the last modification that we have done on the input image. It works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if relevant to your case, but I was running into this same error message attempting to run the sample from the Azure custom vision service [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-model-python).

Issue was because I'd given the graph a name when importing it - but should have left it as an empty string here: `tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using a model that was exported from Azure custom vision service. In my case, changing the name of the output tensor from 'loss' to 'model_outputs' worked:

```
output_layer = 'model_outputs:0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when exporting my Custom Vision model. When I use **model_outputs:0** it runs. However the predictions array doen't make sense. When I test the model within Custom Vision I get 4 objects
[Three cars and a truck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxvBh.png)

but the predicition array shape is 13X13X40